# how to get data from the sublinks array

Tags: angular

I need to get all the values for substitution in ng For, I did, but outputs only the first elements

**info.component.html**

```
 <div *ngFor="let infoItem of infoItems" class="info__item">
        <div class="info__title">{{ infoItem.title }}</div>
        <ul class="info__list">
          <li class="info__list_item"><a href="#" class="info__link">{{ infoItem.sublinks[].title }}</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

**info.items.ts**

```
export const INFO_ITEMS: IInfoItem[] = [
  {
    title: 'Company',
    sublinks: [
      {
        title: 'About CyberMetals',
      },
      {
        title: 'Careers',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'My Account',
    sublinks: [
      {
        title: 'Registration',
      },
      {
        title: 'Account Login',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: You need another ngfor in <li> for sublinks, e. g. *ngFor="let sublink of infoItem.sublinks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `*ngFor` for the `sublinks[]` as it's also an array.
The HMTL should be like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let infoItem of infoItems" class="info__item">
  <div class="info__title">{{ infoItem.title }}</div>
  <ul class="info__list">
    <div *ngFor="let sublinks of infoItem.sublinks" class="info__item">
     <li class="info__list_item">
       <a href="#" class="info__link">{{ sublinks.title }}</a>
     </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```